Запятая перед первым и вторым тире при обособлении осложненной вставки
Рассмотрим предложение:
Мне пришло(,) — возможно, по ошибке, как я думаю, —  письмо из другого города.
Вторая запятая ставится, а первая?  Если да или нет, то по какому правилу? Речевые обороты есть и в начале, и в конце вставки. Как они влияют на постановку запятых?
И если мы не ставим первую запятую, то что будет обозначать такой несимметричный знак? (Это в том случае, если знаки вообще что-то обозначают.)

Запятая перед вводным словом не нужна, в данном случае вводное слово примыкает к вставной конструкции и запятая ставится после всей конструкции,т.е. после первого тире.
Ср. примеры из справочника Розенталя.
Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну (Кав.) — вставному предложению предшествует деепричастие, и запятая ставится, после всей этой конструкции;
Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом — вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчинённого предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции.
Во всех примерах на месте " разрыва" предложения вставной конструкцией должна стоять запятая, но она перенесена.
Ср. в нашем примере без вставной конструкции.
Мне пришло письмо из другого города. В этом случае на месте разрыва предложения вставной конструкцией не должно быть никакого знака, к нему примыкает вводное слово и запятая ставится ставится после него.
Однако возможно и постановка запятой пере первом тире в качестве симметричного знака.
Когда я стану умирать, — и, верь, тебе не долго ждать, — ты перенесть меня вели в наш сад (Л.); Когда Косте, сиротке-то, пошёл девятый годок, — а я в ту пору уже невестой была, — повезла я его по всем гимназиям (Ч.);
Но в одном в одном из справочников (Справочник по пунктуации, А в т о р - с о с т а в и т е л ь Н. М. Пипченко)  есть такое предложение.
Он [ветер] дул неизвестно откуда, – казалось, со всех сторон, – хлопал ставнями, пылил,свинцовыми полосами гулял по морю (Пауст.) – запятая связана с вводным словом в начале вставки.

Спасибо, Серж, но в ваших примерах нет обособленного оборота (вводного слова, например) в начале вставки.  Меня такой вариант больше всего интересовал. // И еще вопрос: что означает симметричный знак,  как обосновать его использование? Ведь это не может быть просто авторским капризом.

См. дополнение.

Спасибо, Серж, интересный пример. Вот и мне помнится, что встречалась где-то такое объяснение;  запятая связана с вводным словом в начале вставки.  Возможно, это  связано и с симметричностью  знаков.

Симметричность знака объясняется отдельно там.

Я предполагаю, что связано. А как там объясняется симметричность?

Симметричность уже говорит о том, что это чистая графика.

Графика, да?)  Но графика знаков весьма красноречива и обычно что-то обозначает. Я могу предположить, что в этом случае нет смысловой и интонационной отнесенности вставки к одной из сторон, это несмещенная вставка. Но это версия.

Графика в данном случае символична.

Серж, в конце первого предложения вашего ответа закралась логическая ошибка. // Вы два раза пишете о разрыве вставной конструкции. Хотелось бы уточнить, о каком всё-таки  разрыве идёт речь? // И просмотрите, пожалуйста, весь текст ответа, уж извините, очень много ошибок...

@АлександрСтрелец, спасибо за замечание. Речь идёт о "разрыве" предложения вставной конструкцией.

Серж... Вы так и не прислушались к ещё двум замечаниям :)

@АлександрСтрелец, каком именно?
